# Matlab: save string in a txt file

Tags: matlab

I have a long string with a lot of information, some empty rows and combined numbers and text in it. I tried to save it into txt file but it writes me a txt file with strange/unreadable characters:

Here is my code which does not work:

```
name_log = TPR_E01;
filename = strcat('New_',name_log); 
save ( filename,'newCleanMarker')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`save` writes binary data by default. You can try the `'-ascii'` flag, or better still you can print the string to file

```
fid = fopen( ['New_', name_log], 'w' ); %// open file to writing
fprintf( fid, '%s', newCleanMarker ); %// print string to file
fclose( fid ); %// don't forget to close the file
```

Please see the following man pages

- [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) - how to open a file in Matlab.
- [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) - a good practice to create file names and paths.
- [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btppzj8-1_1) - saving *binary* data, and the use of `'-ascii'` flag.

Comment: It writes me "Error using fprintf;
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

Comment: Here in this issue I have 400x1 cell where at the beginning is some text, some empty rows and then combined text with numbers...Thanks!

Comment: @MareB please provide a **small** example, it is difficult to understand what you want. have you tried the `'-ascii'` option?

Comment: If I do like this: filename = strcat('New_',name_log); save ( filename,'newCleanMarker', '-ascii'), I got this message: "Warning: Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file.
 Variable 'newCleanMarker' not written to file. " And it saves me new file but empty with 0 bytes. 

If I try to use your "fid" version with fprintf I get the message: "Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs."

Comment: *please* provide a **small** example of `newCleanMarker`.

Comment: It is unlikely that I will download binary file (mat) from an unknown source. Please provide **small** example in the means of editing your question and adding a few lines: `newCleanMarker = { 'aaa', 4, [], 'fjdksl\n' }` etc. an example that is both **short** and exhibits the different types of entries you have in your cell array.

Comment: newCleanMarker{1,1} = Marker File, Version 1.0;
newCleanMarker{2,1} = [];
newCleanMarker{3,1} = '[Common Infos]';
newCleanMarker{12,1} = Mk1=New Segment,,1,1,0,20140804123536762549;
newCleanMarker{13,1} = Mk2=Stimulus,S  1,13120;

Comment: I found the solution finally here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25387-write-cell-array-to-text-file
Do you know if there is any other solution that is integrated into matlab functions?